# Host multiple sites under the same hosting account

Tags: dns, subdomain, web-hosting, nameservers

Can I know is it possible to have multiple sites under the same hosting account.

1. public_html/    - Access this via www.example-site.com
2. public_html/site1    - Access this via www.example-site1.com
3. public_html/site2    - Access this via www.example-site2.com

As you can see here, I have purchased three domain names. Now I need to link them into relative folders using Nameserves.

Can I have three different name servers from the same hosting account based on the folders?

How can I set Nameserves to match the correct folder?

(I'm using one HostSG VPS account and 3 goDaddy domain names)

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Do you have cPanel?

Comment: ya I have cPanel access.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your new site as an Addon-Domain From the cpanel. You don't have to create Name Servers to every single site. You Can Point Existing Name Server with all your sites.

Please follow the below link. It will explain in detail how to add an Addon Domain

[Managing Multiple Domains from a Single Hosting Account](https://blog.cpanel.com/managing-multiple-domains-from-a-single-cpanel-account/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option on your cpanel to addons New Domains, once the domain is registered, when you add it, it will automatically create a folder for you with some configuration.